# Get entities that are not linked

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have Items and Lines that are linked with the ItemsLines table.

On a web page, I show an item. I want to display in a DropDownList all Lines that are not linked to this Item.

This doesn't work :

```
int ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

ddlLines.DataSource = context.Lines.Where(t => !t.ItemLines.Any(x => x.ItemId == ItemId));
```

I was trying to get the Lines where(they are not associated to the Item).

I can't figure out how to do this.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT :**

This is the error message I get:

the objectcontext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not because your lambda expression is incorrect.  Your issue is that the context object you are using to connect to your database has already been disposed of before you call:

```
ddlLines.DataSource = context.Lines.Where(t => !t.ItemLines.Any(x => x.ItemId == ItemId));
```

The solution is to add a .ToList() to the end of your expression.  This is because the .Where lambda expression returns something from the IQueryable interface and everything from that interface still has a connection to the database. So by adding .ToList() it will remove the connection to the database.

Comment: With linq to entities, how would you select distinct lines?

Comment: Got it : (from t in context.ItemLines
                                  where t.ItemId != ItemId
                                  select t.Line).Distinct()

Comment: @JoRouss Thanks for the additional info, I didn't think about the .Distinct().  Glad I could help!

Comment: Your expression won't work since I want Lines that are not associated with this Item only. If i have another Item linked to a Line that is not linked to this Item, your expression will return it.

Answer (score 0):

First, the error message is because the context has been disposed (I assume you are using it inside a 'using' block, which means the context has been disposed by the time the actual data binding occurs). If you intend to directly bind to the items, you may want to use projection, which will create a new instance that is not connected to the DataContext:

```
ddlLines.DataSource = context.Lines.Where(
  t => !t.ItemLines.Any(x => x.ItemId == ItemId)
).Select(
t => new 
{
    SomeProperty = t.SomeProperty, 
    SomeOtherProperty = t.SomeOtherProperty }).ToList();
// Where SomeProperty and SomeOtherProperty are the display/value fields, etc.
```

Second, you might want to consider using Except for this instead of your lambda. It'll return an IEnumerable of all things NOT in the set you supply, and it's a bit cleaner:

```
ddlLines.DataSource = context.Lines.Except(new int[] { ItemId }).Select(...).ToList();
```